# c++ function that pass by right reference confusion

Tags: c++, function, casting, pass-by-reference, compile-time

I was looking at the source code of the std::move function. What it does is to remove the reference and add a right reference(&&).

```
/**
*  @brief  Convert a value to an rvalue.
*  @param  __t  A thing of arbitrary type.
*  @return The parameter cast to an rvalue-reference to allow moving it.
*/
template<typename _Tp>
  constexpr typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&
  move(_Tp&& __t) noexcept
  { return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&>(__t); }
```

So, I was wondering if I can make a right reference and pass it to the function? So, here it is:

```
void f1(int&&) { std::cout << 1; }
void f1(int&) { std::cout << 2; }

int main() {

  int&& x = 1;
  f1(static_cast<decltype(x)>(x));
  f1(static_cast<int&&>(x));
  f1(x);
}
```

And, output: 112

I figured out that x is type of int&& because first two f1 do the same thing. But, what about the third one? Isn't it an int&& ? Why do I have to static_cast it in order to use it like a right reference?
I know there is a clam in "c++ templates complete guide" which is:

> The fact that move semantics is not automatically passed through is intentional
>   and important. If it weren’t, we would lose the value of a movable object the first time we use it in a function.

I am still curious why they select different function at compile time even they have the same type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing types and [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), they're different things.

As a named variable, `x`'s value category is lvalue, (its type is `int&&`.) lvalues could be bound to lvalue-reference, but can't be bound to rvalue-reference. So given `f1(x);`, `f1(int&)` will be selected.

To get `f1(int&&)` to be called you need to convert it to rvalue. The 1st and 2nd one select `f1(int&&)` because explicit conversion make rvalue expressions (more precisely xvalue expressions); which could be bound to rvalue-reference. And `std::move` works in similar way too.

> The following expressions are xvalue expressions:
>
> - a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is rvalue reference to object, such as `std::move(x)`;
> - ...
> - a cast expression to rvalue reference to object type, such as `static_cast<char&&>(x)`;
> - ...

Comment: Ah.. I got u. Types and value categories are different things. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ForrestSun Yes, definitely.